# Is "update-initramfs -u" needed after adding or removing a module with "modprobe"?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, kernel-modules

Most instructions that I find online about adding or replacing kernel modules in Ubuntu only mention `modprobe` and `rmmod`.  However, according my experience with `e1000e`, the modification is reverted after reboot unless I do `update-initramfs -u` afterwards.  The `man` page of `update-initramfs` does not mention modules.

So, is it always necessary to run `update-initramfs -u` after replacing kernel modules if I want to have the modified kernel after reboot?

Comment: Using the /etc/modprobe.d directory is also an option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess this is about some Linux distribution that is part of the Debian/Ubuntu family, as `update-initramfs` is part of Debian `initramfs-tools`.

If the module (and the command to load it) is included in initramfs, then `update-initramfs -u` is needed: if you don't do it, initramfs will still contain the old state (= old version of the module and the command to load it).

If you are uncertain whether or not the module is included in initramfs, use the `lsinitramfs` command to view the contents of your initramfs. For example:

```
$ lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-5-amd64 |less
```

However, running `update-initramfs -u` should generally never hurt, so if you are uncertain, you can just run it to err on the safe side.